# Restrict 'yum update' to partial version number

Tags: rhel, yum

I'd like to restrict `yum update` such that it will only apply minor version upgrades to certain packages and will ignore major updates.

For example: if I have `puppet-3.8.3-1.el7.noarch` installed, I'm quite happy to go to `3.8.4`, but *not* to `4.0.anything`.

I'm aware of the [versionlock](http://linux.die.net/man/1/yum-versionlock) plugin to `yum`, but it only appears to support wildcarding in a very restricted fashion, and my attempts to put something like

```
0:puppet-3.8.*
```

in `versionlock.list` have no effect.

Is there a way of getting `yum` to do what I want?

Comment: Re: "my attempts have no affect" - what is the actual result, e.g. what you see with `yum -v update` and what other puppet dependencies do you have installed? What if you use e.g. `yum versionlock add \*puppet-3.8\*` and what do you see with `yum versionlock list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no wildcards in the locklist itself, you can use wildcards when using the commands "versionlock add" but it will only match packages that currently exist.

Probably the easiest way to solve your problem is to add excludes for the things you don't want, Eg.:

excludes = puppet-4.* puppet-3.9*

But note that this is guessing, as puppet-3.8.999 isn't necessarily a good upgrade. And if RHEL put out a puppet-3.9 that won't necessarily be a bad upgrade.

Comment: Yeah, I've come to the same conclusion about `versionlock` from reading the source.  Clearly I'd need to make a decision as to any version 3.9.x, but at least this would stop an unconsidered upgrade.  Many thanks for your answer.